# How to use Selenium Web Driver to test apps developed using electron framework

Tags: c#, selenium, electron

Please refer to these images to get an idea
[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQcB2.png)
[Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAiXa.png)
I am using Selenium web driver with C# for automation using VS2015. One of the apps which I have to test is developed using the electron framework. I have gone through the documentation in the Electron project
but I am still struggling to understand how it works. I have written this code to open my electron application, it actually opens the electron window but fails to open the Index.html page in the electron shell.This is my code in C#

```
ChromeOptions electronOption = new ChromeOptions();
//path to eletron Binary
electronOption.BinaryLocation =
      "C:\\mydev\\electron-quick-start-master\\node_modules\\electron\\dist\\electron.exe";
//Path to the Electron App
electronOption.AddArgument("C:\\mydev\\electron-quick-start-master\\");
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Chrome");
capability.SetCapability("chromeOptions", electronOption);
DriverContext.Driver = new ChromeDriver(electronOption);
```

Can someone please explain me here what `//Path to the Electron App` means. I have also seen this in the link which I have presented you. If I run the same commands above in command line like below it actually opens the `index.html` page in the electron shell. The following are the commands for command line

`C:\mydev\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\electron\dist\electron.exe C:\mydev\electron-quick-start-master\`

Can someone please help me understand how to work with it. If any one can post me a simple C# code to input into a app containing the textbox using electron framework, it will really help me to understand the flow.

Comment: Do you want to know what  `//` means? Or `electronOpion.BinaryLocation`?

Comment: Hi Paul,Thanks for the reply I want to know what does "Path to the Electron App" means. I n my above example I assume its this C:\\mydev\\electron-quick-start-master\\ part that's where the main.js file resides. So as I mentioned above if I use the command prompr like above it can open the index.html in electron but not using my C# code above.

Comment: Please refer to the images I have just uploaded to get an idea.

Comment: Electron officially recommend using JS and Spectron to do this. If you want to use C#, then you're off to a good start. You don't need the `DesiredCapabilities` since you're using the `ChromeOptions` directly. Are you getting an error or exception when you're starting your driver? Can you include that?

Comment: No it just runs without any errors,it just opens up the electron shell window and does not open the html page in it as indicated in the image link in my original post.Please follow the image links "Command Prompt" and "Test Case".

Comment: Are you going to any page in your app? It may be working. Have a look at `Driver.get()`. You probably need to use that to naviage to index.html

Comment: Hi Paul,Sorry for the delayed response. In context to my original question,I found the reason why the index.html was not being opened in the electron shell. The reason was my sample application was not built. Looking at the exe I thought it was a built app but was not. I know I sound dumb here but that was the case. Once you build your electron app then my code sample above will work. And yes regarding your question of navigating to index.html,you dont have to do this as once you build your project ,and click on the exe it will automatically open the index.html

Comment: Hi Bharadwaj, I am also in the process of trying to set up testing an electron app with C#. If you don't mind, would you be willing to let me see how your main test app in C# is written?

Comment: @HarveyLin sorry for the delayed response,let me know if you stil need help in setting up the electron app using selenium ,C# can help you out.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Pappu thanks for the reply, I have been using selenium under node.js