# Error while Selenium Web Driver initializing with electron shell

Tags: c#, shell, selenium, electron

could you give some advice, why i'm getting following WebDriverException: "An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:61516/session timed out after 60 seconds." Here is my Chrome driver setup:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Users\...\Shell.exe";
return new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I see 2 processes with shell in Task Manager, and ScriptedSandbox64.exe with increasing memory consumption. After 60 sec i'm getting WebDriverException. (C#, Selenium, Electron). Thanks in advance.

[Task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qYfO.png)

Issue very close to [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392969/how-to-use-selenium-web-driver-to-test-apps-developed-using-electron-framework)

Comment: What code is running on localhost? First use a simple page and test if that works.

Comment: Updated last row to below: return new ChromeDriver(@"C:\New folder\..", options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180)); and now i'm getting InvalidOperationException: 
Additional information: unknown error: unable to discover open pages